# Is there a 'playground' where one can experiment with SE editing features in titles?

Tags: support, edits

I just asked [this question](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/preserve-or-remove-the-special-formula-formatting-in-the-question-title) on meta.earthscience.SE and while writing it thought *Maybe it's possible to have subscripts in a title using other tags?*.

Is there a way (place) to experiment with things like that without actually changing the title?
For question/answer text it's easy because you immediately see the preview when editing.

I don't want to save my experiment and then revert the edit, that's polluting the system.

Comment: Can we stop all these chatty comments, please? 1) The question is about the title, not the comments 2) That is what the formatting sandbox is for

Comment: @Arjan Indeed, <sub> did not work in the sandbox

Comment: You mean the HTML `<sub>` or the Unicode ₂³?

Comment: @Arjan <sub> (and then I have to add some more text to make the comment long enough)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the StackExchange [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122) question:

> You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. You can
>
> - edit this question itself (Community Wiki questions such as this one require 100 reputation to edit)
> - post answers to this question (Since this question is protected, this requires earning 10 reputation on this site)
> - post comments to this question or its answers
> - test suspected bugs with the editor

Just remember to roll back any test edit that changes the question itself. Since that's the goal of the question, it's not considered "polluting the system".